# Dataframe conversion using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the records which are in below format:

```
      ATL        ORD        DEN         MSP        DFW        DTW 
    18554      711.179     382.411   9485.764   9247.194   7148.939
```

I need to convert them into a dataframe of below format

```
     city    value
     ATL     18554
     ORD     711.179
     DEN     382.411
     MSP     9485.764
     DFW     9247.194
     DTW     7148.939
```

I am using R and tried the simple dataframe conversion syntax, data.frame(), but the result I am getting is provided below:

```
             value
         ATL 18554
         ORD 711.179
         DEN 382.411
         MSP 9485.764
         DFW 9247.194
```

Only the 'value' is formed as a new column in the resultant dataframe but the city column is not defined. I think city is being treated as index in the resultant dataframe(not sure though).

df[[1]] is yielding me:

```
    18554
    711.179
    382.411
    9485.764
    9247.194
    7148.939
```

But this should be the result of df[[2]] and df[[1]] should give me below result:

```
   ATL     
   ORD     
   DEN     
   MSP     
   DFW    
   DTW
```

Could someone help me on achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your first data is a named numeric.

When you use the `data.frame()` fucntion, your `row.names` is getting set to the names. Do this:

```
df$city <- row.names(df)
row.names(df) <- c(1:nrow(df))
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your original data is a named vector `vec1`, you can try this:

```
df <- data.frame(city=names(vec1), value=vec1, row.names = NULL)
> df
#  city     value
#1  ATL 18554.000
#2  ORD   711.179
#3  DEN   382.411
#4  MSP  9485.764
#5  DFW  9247.194
#6  DTW  7148.939
```

**data**

```
vec1 <- setNames(c(18554, 711.179, 382.411, 9485.764, 9247.194, 7148.939), 
                 c("ATL", "ORD", "DEN", "MSP", "DFW", "DTW"))
```